# Get path from OLE Object Link MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ole

I have a couple tables in a database that use OLE Objects as links to files on network drives. I used the module from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199066 to try to get the path from the OLE Objects but all I get is links to .ico or .exe rather than the actual path. If I double click on the Links field value the files open correctly from the network location.[image: Screen Capture]

Answer (score 0):

The properties you seek is as following,

You should

```
Dim Ref As Reference
For Each Ref In References

   MsgBox Ref.Name & " > " & Ref.FullPath 

Next
```

Will give you names and paths as message.